# Weird trailing effect during css animation

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, css-animations

I am creating an animation while I got this weird issue. Below is a code snippet with a single `div` with some styles and animation applied to it.

When I run the code, during the animation, I can see a weird trailing effect on the extreme right side of the square.

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-image: radial-gradient(pink, hotpink);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
}

@keyframes zoominout{
    0%{
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
    50%{
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}

#outer{
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 450px;
    width: 450px;
    animation: zoominout infinite 4s;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer"></div>
```

Whenever I click anywhere or press any button, the trails disappear.

What could be causing this and how should I solve this issue?

Also, this issue occurs only with borders. Without borders, no issue is there.

**Update** - This issue is with chrome browser only. While using firefox, no trailing lines are visible.

Comment: Which browser did you use? I couldn't see any issue! Try using different browsers

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti  I am using Chrome. I have tried running the same code in Firefox and its working fine. Is this issue related to Chrome only or is it because of another reason?

Comment: Not really sure though, cause right now I'm using chrome on macbook, and I did not see anything

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti that’s interesting because I didn’t see the problem with Chrome (or with Safari) on IOS either, apart from tiny flickering, so it’s sort of both browser and OS dependent.

Comment: @AHaworth yeah I guess so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be your borders that are scaling but somehow remain behind in faded form.

If we take a more minimal example - no border radius, no flexing, you can see it clearly on this square. The first has animation duration 4s and shows separate lines which is what you get but in small form on the circle. The second has animation duration 40s and show more continuous as would be expected as more frames would be possible in the time.
[image]  [image]

Here's the snippet:

```html
<style>
@keyframes zoominout{
    0%{
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
    50%{
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}

#outer{
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-color: magenta;
    height: 450px;
    width: 450px;
    animation: zoominout infinite 4s;
    background-color: cyan;
}
</style>
<div id="outer"></div>
```

So, what to do about it? Somehow the borders aren't totally disappearing but are fading.

Update: here's a quick workaround - animating dimensions rather than scaling. I know it's not the best way to animate (as it possibly isn't using the GPU???) but it seems to work. Of course you'd want to put your circle (now a square) into a container which has the actual width and then use %s. It worked on Chrome, Edge, Firefox on Windows 10 and Safari and Chrome on IOS14. It also removed the slight flicker that was previously seen on Firefox and Safari [which had both worked better on the initial code than Edge or Chrome on Win10].

Snippet with workaround:

```html
<style>
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-image: radial-gradient(pink, hotpink);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
}

@keyframes zoominout{
    0%{
        width: var(--w);
        height: var(--w);
    }
    50%{
        width: calc(var(--w) * 1.1);
        height: calc(var(--w) * 1.1);
    }
    100%{
        width: var(--w);
        height: var(--w);
    }
}


#outer{
    --w: 450px;/* you don't have to use a CSS variable but this is just to make it easier to change the width/height if you need to */
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: var(--w);
    width: var(--w);
    animation: zoominout infinite 4s;
}

</style>
  <div id="outer"></div>
```

Comment: True. This effect only appears with border. Without border, it is ok. But, I can see this issue only in chrome browser. In firefox, this runs as expected, without trailing lines. So is this issue only browser related, or it has to do something with something else?

Comment: I see the effect on Edge as well as Chrome (WIndows 10) which is to be expected as they are basically the same. Firefox on Windows10 does not show it, though there is a bit of a flickery effect on my laptop which I guess is as the borders are recalculated and hit fractions of a pixel. Safari on IOS 14 (iPad)  doesn't show it though still a very slight flickery effect. Chrome on IOS doesn't show it either.

Comment: So can we do anything about it? Or we have to change our browsers?

Comment: There's a workaround with animating dimensions. I'll just do a snippet and add it to the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: I've put the workaround snippet and explanation in the answer. I know animating dimensions isn't the most efficient - but it's better than having the wrong result for the user and there didn't seem to be any ill-effects on my laptop (e.g. fan not coming on as it repeated the animation) so it's likely to be useable in practice on all the browsers we've tried.

Comment: Thanks. Will use the workaround for now. Hope that the issue with `scale()` will be solved in near future with browser updates.